# Unable to enter the home directory

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, user-accounts

Panel *ISPmanager* set up user `domain_name`. I want to add another user (`dev_2`), who is also involved in the development of the site. Gets the list of user groups for `domain_name`:

```
root@server:~# groups domain_name
domain_name : domain_name mgrsecure
```

Based on their knowledge, I am entering the following commands in a terminal:

```
root@server:~# useradd  -g domain_name -d /var/www/domain_name/data dev_2
root@server:~# passwd dev_2
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
root@server:~# usermod -a -G mgrsecure dev_2
```

Control:

```
root@server:~# groups dev_2
dev_2 : domain_name mgrsecure
```

When I try to go to the server as a user `dev_2`, the server writes the following error:

```
 $ ssh   dev_2@server_ip
dev_2@server_ip's password: 
Linux wth 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64
Could not chdir to home directory /var/www/domain_name/data: Permission denied
-bash: /var/www/domain_name/data/.bash_profile: Permission denied


dev_2@server:/$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /var/www/lider.top/data`?

Comment: @TomYan ls: cannot access /var/www/lider.top/data: Permission denied

Comment: Sorry I meant run it as root / with sudo.

Comment: who (what user/group) owns /var/www/domain_name/data ?  run the following command: `ls -l /var/www/domain_name/data` and tell us what user/group owns that folder.   If you did not chown that directory, I am going to guess that file will be owned by root, which would make sense why you cannot write to that directory using your dev2 account.